# How to keep looping Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a function that is very repetitive. I would like to keep looping instead of having all this code

Comment: Can you explain what the code is meant to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax by appropriate modification:

```
for i in range(2,6):
    df['finalvalue{}'.format(i)] = df.iloc[::-1, :].groupby([df.id, df['finalvalue{}'.format(i-1)].diff().lt(0).cumsum()])['finalvalue{}'.format(i-1)].cumsum()
```